# React Redux : get error after refresh page

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux

I amd using reduxjs toolkit with react project, I tried fetch api with createAsyncThunk but get error : `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`
first it is load correctly and get data ,but after refresh i got error

reducer : menuSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
 import axios from "axios";
 import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
 const cookies = new Cookies();
 const title=cookies.get('title')
 const token=cookies.get('token')
 export const fetchMenu = createAsyncThunk(
"getMenuItems/title",
 async () => {
 let url = `https://xxxxxxxx/getMenuItems/${title}`;
 let data = await axios.get(url, {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  });
  return data.data;
  }
 );
 export const menuSlice = createSlice({
 name: "menu",
 initialState: {
 menu: [],
   status: false,
 },
 extraReducers: {
  [fetchMenu.pending]: (state, action) => {
    state.status = true;
  },
  [fetchMenu.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = false;
  state.menu = action.payload;
 },
 [fetchMenu.rejected]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = false;
   },
  },
 });
 export default menuSlice.reducer
```

Home page :

```
const title = cookies.get("title");
const token = cookies.get("token");
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(fetchMenu());
}, []);
if (status) {
  return <div>...Loading</div>;
}
return (
<div className="row d-flex w-100 h-100 justify-content-center mx-auto px-0 ">
  <div className="row d-flex col-md-9 col-lg-9 justify-content-center col-sm-12 mx-auto px-0">
    <div className="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-12">
      <Menu siteData={menu} siteId={title} />
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-sm-12 bg-light "><Edit siteData={menu} siteId={title}       /></div>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-12 ">
    <input onClick={logOut} type="button" name="" id="" value="LogOut" />
  </div>
 </div>
);
```

I load menu state in Menu component

Comment: In the code snippets you have shared I don't see anything referencing a `length` property. Can you [edit] the post to include the complete error message and error stacktrace, and any other relevant code as part of a complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese this component <Menu siteData={menu} siteId={title} /> is pass menu which is have length

Comment: Then please [edit] the post to include the `Edit` component and any other relevant code you are working with so we can see what it's doing. We can't address issues in code we can't see. If you can, please also try to include (a) the response value from the browser dev tools for the URL request that `fetchMenu` makes, and (b) the returned value of `data` in the `fetchMenu` thunk.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that the problem is connected to `status`. In your menuSlice `status` in initialState is **false**, that's why on component render, this piece of code will be ignored:

```
if (status) {
  return <div>...Loading</div>;
}
```

It would be better if you depended on `menu` state. You can change your code a bit to this:

```
initialState: {
 menu: null,
   status: false,
 },
```

And then:

```
return (
  menu && (
    <div className="row d-flex w-100 h-100 justify-content-center mx-auto px-0 ">
    <div className="row d-flex col-md-9 col-lg-9 justify-content-center col-sm-12 mx-auto px-0">
      <div className="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-12">
        <Menu siteData={menu} siteId={title} />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-sm-12 bg-light "><Edit siteData={menu} siteId={title}       /></div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-12 ">
      <input onClick={logOut} type="button" name="" id="" value="LogOut" />
    </div>
   </div>
  )

  );
```

So, if menu does exist, the component will render.
Hope it helps.